# xx' property on 'yyy could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'

Tags: entity-framework

I am facing this problem due to unknown reason and I have tried every forum and blog for solving this but could not get any satisfactory answer for this.

Let me describe the scenario.

I have a view in database which is consisting columns from two tables. None of the tables have any column with data type "int" hence the resultant view (let's name is "MyRecord") also does not have any column with "int" data types. All the columns in the view have varchar as datatype.

Now, in my .edmx I am adding this view and the model is created (with name "MyRecord") fine with all the properties are created fine with datatype "String". I am using Silverlight with RIA services, to after builing the application related proxies are also created fine without any confiction.

The problem starts when I try to query the "MyRecord" using my domain context, I am getting following error.

**Load operation failed for query 'GetMyRecords'. The 'CenterCode' property on 'MyRecord' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.**

As seen in the error, it is clearly forcing me to convert data type of "string" column "CenterCode" to the "Int32" which is totally useless and unnecessary for me. The "String" or "varchar" columns are there because they have some business importance and changing them to "Int32" or "int" might break the application in future. Its true that "CenterCode" column has numeric data only in it but there can be character data in future thats why it is created with 'varchar' datatype.

I can not change type of my data just because EF is not supporting.

I used sql server profiler, the query is being executed correct and I can run the same query in SSMS without any error. The error comes in the application only when EF is building objects from the data returned by the query.

I am failed to understand why Entity Framework is throwing this error, it is simply not converting "varchar" to "String" and unnecessarily bringing "Int32" in picture and making the life difficult. I am struggling with this issue since last 4 hours and tried every possible way to resolve it but everything is in vein.

Please provide some information or solution on this if anyone is having it.

EF team, you must have some answer to this question or work around for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a `double` datatype.

**Solution**:

Change your view/procedure and cast the column like:`cast(columnname as int32)`

Comment: I'm wondering, even if this works, how does it make sense?  From what I understand the question opener said his table does not contain any int datatypes and are supposed to all be varchar.  Why would casting as int32 be needed?  Or rather why is EF trying to bring int into the equation if none of the fields are ints?  I have the same issue, but with double as well and I'm trying to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this problem or not, but I just ran into something like this while working on multiple result sets with EF. In my case, I had `reader.NextResult()` that was causing a problem for me because I hadn't read all the records from the previous result and I think EF was failing due to trying to map data from the second result set into the first object.

Answer (score 1):

`CAST(columnName as Type)` solve my problem in stored procedure.